# "Расшарить" два Java web application между собой

Tags: java-ee, web-apps, servlet, tomcat, java

Добрый день.
Ситуация такая - есть Tomcat, на нем крутится Alfresco ([ECM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management)) и BIRT (отчеты). Необходимо сделать так, что бы из модулей (jar) или страниц (jsp) BIRT'a можно было иметь доступ к "сервисам" Alfresco (по простому: они предоставляют доступ к различным типа данных репозитория ECM).
Alfresco использует [Spring Framework](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework).
Есть java-класс, который получает текущий servlet(BIRT'а).

```
public void initialize(HttpServlet servlet) {
        servletContext = servlet.getServletContext();
}
```

Пытаюсь получить доступ к bean следующим образом:

```
ServletContext alfrescoWebContext = servletContext.getContext("/alfresco");

WebApplicationContext alfrescoSpringContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
        .getWebApplicationContext(alfrescoWebContext);

// serviceRegistry объект типа ServiceRegistry - относится к API Alfresco
serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) AlfrescoSpringContext
        .getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);
```

При попытке работать таки образом вылетает следующее:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Aug 01 10:01:04 MSK 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

Структура проектов такая:

```
tomcat
|_  webapps
    |_  alfresco
    |_  birt
```

Как такое решить? Может быть есть другой способ?

============================================

Вопрос решился с помощью вытягивания атрибутов из контекста, спасибо [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) за наводку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не силен в Spring'е, но из общих положений известно, что:

1. Просто так обмен данными между различными контекстами в общем случае запрещен, требуются специальные манипуляции на уровне сервера для разрешения этого.
2. Даже если обмен данными разрешен, все равно каждый контекст имеет собственный менеджер сессий, так что в идеале надо еще и передавать между контекстами сессии (если требуется получать данные привязанные к сессиям - то бишь `getAttribute()`).

Применительно к Tomcat, если мне память не изменяет в настройках server.xml надо прописать что-то вроде:

```
<Host>
  <Context path="/alfresco" crossContext="true" />
  <Context path="/birt" crossContext="true" />
</Host>
```

Тогда будет возможен доступен кроссконтекстный обмен данными.

Comment: crossContext="true" - уже выставлен, и проблему не решил =\
А общая картина "получения" верная? Т.е. необходимо с сервером покопаться?

Comment: Ну вроде все верно, единственное, что когда вы пытаетесь получить констект Spring'а, находясь в Birt'е - у вас это проваливается - что видимо связано с тем, что Birt ничего не знает о Spring'е, поэтому попробуйте получить не спринговские атрибуты или же в Alfresco складывайте в контекст специальные атрибуты для Birt'а